# What is the end result of running a machine learning algorithm on a data-set look like?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

So I'm reading some research papers on machine learning applied to classification algorithms and one of the steps in the algorithm psuedo-code says: **"Obtain classification prediction *P* from machine learning classification algorithm"**.

My questions is what does this *multiclass* classification prediction *P* look like?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a vector, whose length equals the number of classes. Each element i in that vector is the probability that the data belongs to class i. Is that what you are asking for?

Edit: that would be the answer for one example, for the whole data set, you would get a number of those answers, one for each example in the set.

Comment: How are the class probabilities of a new item determined? It's feature/attribute values have to pass through some equation?

Comment: They are the output of the classification algorithm. It's rarely (or never?) result of a single equation, but rather the return value of an algorithm (something like logistic regression or a support vector machine, for example).